# Mega menu with flex, divide into 4 columns automatically

Tags: html, css, wordpress, flexbox, menu

I'm trying to build a mega menu with flexbox. The only issue I have left figuring out how I can "Redskap & tillbehör" into 3 columns so it fills the column before and after it. Right now it's just cutting out some of the items.

http://dataring.se/dev/wiggs3/

[Here is how I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8XQB.jpg)

Comment: please add your code not a link/image

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve 4 column menu layout with very basic css that solves your use case. Additional styling as per your design guidelines you can include to this

```css
body {
  margin:  0;
}
ul {
  padding:  0;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu-items {
  columns: 4;
  display: none;
}

.menu > li:hover .menu-items {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Main Menu</a>

      <ul class="menu-items">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Menu Item Header</a>
          <ul>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Menu Item Header</a>
          <ul>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Menu Item Header</a>
          <ul>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Menu Item Header</a>
          <ul>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Menu Item Header</a>
          <ul>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```